# MVC3: Pass ICollection from View to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, controller, icollection

I have a model with an property of type icollection.

```
public class myClass{
   public string param1{get; set;}
   public string param2{get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<myClass2> param3{get; set;}

   public myClass()
   {
       param3 = new hashSet<myClass2>();
   }

}

public class myClass2{
   public string param4{get; set;}
   public string param5{get; set;}
   public virtual myClass param6{get; set;}
}
```

I pass the model containing these two class to my view and am able to see the items in my icollection by using `foreach(var item in Model.myClass.param3)`

And I store the items in a hidden field to retrieve it in my controller

```
foreach(var item in Model.myClass.param3){
      @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.parm4);
      @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.parm5);
 }
```

But when I submit the form and pass the model to the controller, I get a count = 0 when calling model.myClass.param3.

How can I pass an ICollection to my view?
I tried [this link](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) but do not know why it is not working.

**EDIT**

The link uses the class Book as a list in order to index (suggesting I should cast the ICollection to a list). How do I do that? Also, if I cast it to a list how do i pass that to the controller as the controller expects to receive an ICollectiion?

Comment: The linked [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) describes how to do it. Can you post what you tried based on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a foreach loop for that, you have to use a for loop.

```
for (int i=0; i<Model.MyClass.param3.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor( model => model.MyClass.param3[i])
    }
```

The reason for this is the `HiddenFor` helper needs some way of assigning unique names to each field for the model binding to work.  The `i` variable accomplishes this.

In your case you;ll need to do some refactoring to implement this.  I don't think `ICollection` or `HashSet` supports indexing, so you'll need to cast it to a `List` or some collection that does support indexing.

See [this excellent blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) on the subject.

Comment: Yes, I thought so too, but model.MyClass.param3[i] works if param3 is a list. But mine is an ICollection, hence doing this give me the error: cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type system.collection.generic.icollection

Comment: Correct, that's why I said you need to cast it to a list, or some collection that supports indexing.

Comment: Simple answer:  Change `public virtual ICollection<myClass2> param3{get; set;}` to `public virtual IList<myClass2> param3{get; set;}` and `param3 = new hashSet<myClass2>();` to `param3 = new List<myClass2>();`

Comment: Thank you! Does that mean Icollection cannot be used passed from view to controller?

Comment: Not necessarily, but in your case using a `List` makes things **much** easier.